# window.close() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to close current browser tab.

**I have tried following**

```
window.close();
```

and

```
  var win = window.open('', '_self');
  win.close();
```

But these are working fine in `chrome` but not working in `firefox`.
I have researched also on google but I didn't find any solution.

I know these question is posted before but I have seen theme and I didn't find solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

The first step is to fool the browser into thinking that it was opened with a script...

```
window.open('','_parent','');
```

This opens a new page, (non-existent), into a target frame/window, (_parent which of course is the window in which the script is executed), and defines parameters such as window size etc, (in this case none are defined as none are needed). Now that the browser thinks a script opened a page we can quickly close it in the standard way...

```
window.close();
```

In Mozilla by default the "dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows" value which controls the Java Script close window is set to "false". In order to fix this issue change this value to "true"

1. Location of the File:

   `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\greprefs\all.js`

change `"dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows" from "false" to "true"`

Example:

Default value

`pref("dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows", false);`

Change it to:

`pref("dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows", true);`

2.Close `Mozilla browser`

3.Try accessing HTML page which has `window.close()` code snippet

Comment: This is also not working

Comment: you need to edit the settings of your firefox.. `about.config -> dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows = true;`

Comment: I updated my answer. you can check it

Comment: Is this for only my browser if yes then how this working for users

Comment: As of now.. for all the forum i have searched.. there's no way to work the solution above unless the user manually allow FF to execute that script.

Comment: This is not working for mozilla.

Comment: You mean about:config